# Mach-Zehnder interferometer classical field

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, interferometry

I knew that

$$I \propto |E|^2$$

I wanted to calculate intensity on detector 1 and detector 2 in Mach-Zehnder interferometer.
One path have electric field $E_{1}$ and the second $E_{2}$. Its splits in first beam splitter into

$$E_{1} = E_{01} \sin( \omega t)$$

and in the

$$E_{2} = E_{02} \sin( \omega t + \varphi)$$

on the second path.

So after going throw second beam splitter intensity on the first detector should be equal to second detector i. e.

$$I_{1}=I_{2} = |E_{1}+E_{2}|^2$$

But I know it is not right. This is classical case so beam splitter is 50:50.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more? This is not enough to know what you want and besides there are tons of .pdf online from universities showing how to derive a Mach-Zehnder's detector intensity.

Comment: @JoséAndrade I've elaborated more.

Comment: does [this](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall06/cos576/papers/zetie_et_al_mach_zehnder00.pdf) answer your question?

Comment: I wanted to get a phase value from the electric field equations, document do not contain information about it.

Comment: Ok, then I do not understand what you want to know, because the file I gave you specifically says that after the second beam-splitter, one arm has an additional $\pi$ shift, leading then to the actual case of a Mach-Zehnder interferometer where the interference pattern in one detector is the opposite of that of the other detector.

Comment: So, on your question you say you want to calculate the intensity on the detectors, however something is wrong. The problem is the non-existent $\pi$ shift from the reflection inside the splitter, which people forget to include. Which means that in the eqs you presented, $I_1 \neq I_2$. But in the comments now you want to get a phase value from E field eqs? That is not the same question...

Comment: I wanted to calculate it in this way: https://scientificsentence.net/Waves/index.php?key=yes&Integer=interferometers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the 2nd beamsplitter you need to consider that each detector has its set of E-fields:

\begin{equation}
I_1=\lvert{E_{11}+E_{12}}\rvert ^2\\
I_2=\lvert{E_{21}+E_{22}}\rvert ^2
\end{equation}

where (using your own eqs):

\begin{equation}
E_{11}=E_{21}=E_{1}\\
E_{12}=E_{2}
\end{equation}
however

\begin{equation}
E_{22}=E_{02}\sin(\omega t - kx + \varphi +\pi)
\end{equation}

Which means $I_1 \neq I_2$, rather the inverse of each other.

Comment: Phase $\pi$ appeared from nowhere, I feel it should be calculated, how to do this?

Comment: from the pdf I linked in the original question: [here](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall06/cos576/papers/zetie_et_al_mach_zehnder00.pdf)